# Android Studio - Retrieving data from firebase is not working

Tags: android, firebase-realtime-database

I'm working on retrieving some data from Firebase and i followed some Youtube tutorials that were working fine,

but out of nowhere the retrieving is not working anymore,

the path that i'm setting is correct but i get an empty list even though there is data from where i am retrieving.

```
private ListView mListView;
private ArrayList<String> mHospitalNames= new ArrayList<>();
private Firebase mRefRoot;
```

this is the path:

```
mRefRoot=new Firebase("https://prototype-d2a84.firebaseio.com/Search/"+countryName+"/"+mCity+"/"+bloodType);
```

this is the code that i am using:

```
   mListView = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listview);

    final ArrayAdapter<String> mArrayAdapter= new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1, mHospitalNames);

    mListView.setAdapter(mArrayAdapter);

    mRefRoot.addChildEventListener(new ChildEventListener() {
        @Override
        public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

            String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
            mHospitalNames.add(value);
            mArrayAdapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
        }

        @Override
        public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {

        }

        @Override
        public void onCancelled(FirebaseError firebaseError) {

        }
    });
```

this is how my database looks like

[image]

can someone tell me whats wrong?

Comment: Maybe you forgot to `setLayoutManager()`? If not, then perhaps provide part of your database structure, maybe we can get something to analyze

Comment: @koceeng i don't have a `setLayoutManager()` where should i add it? I added now a screenshot of my database structure. Thank you for helping

Comment: After you initialize your list view, add this `mListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this))`. If that work, maybe I'll explain further

Comment: Is it supposed to add Index API code for the `setLayoutManager`?

Comment: Honestly, I don't know why you mention Index API. Let me ask you first, in your log, is there any `"No adapter attached; skipping layout"`? If yes, then I can answer you confidently. But if no, then my solution above maybe not working for this case

Comment: No, there isn't any. when i added the line `mListView.setLayoutManager(new LinearLayoutManager(this));` the `setLayoutManager` method was red, so it told me to add the Index API code for it work, i did so but didn't work. Apparently the method is not available for the listview. But Thank you very much for trying.

Comment: How is your String.class look like, also try to change the structure of the database. Firebase uses random values as key and fetches them all.

Comment: I think `String.class` is just a basic string. Its like `getValue().toString()`. And @YaraRammal, try to put `Log.e(...)` inside `onChildAdded` to see if your code run through it or not

Answer (score 1):

Check if the rules in your database are set to true if you are not using authentication

```
{
  "rules": {
    ".read": "true",
    ".write": "true"
  }
}
```

if that is not the problem then check what your datasnapshot is returning.If your database is something like this

```
root
  -country
     -city
       -bloodgroup
          -B+
            -123:something
            -111:something
```

then you have to give the key for which you want to get the value. example

datasnapshot.child("B+").child("123").getValue();//for first child i.e 123
datasnapshot.child("B+").child("111").getValue();//for second child i.e 111

else if you want the entire set of values then, you can use the above line multiple times with different key or use a class to get all the values at once.

As per your database you have keys as numbers,i would suggest to change that and keep strings as this would cause problem in retrieving data if you use a class.

```
class mClass{
 private String first;
 private String second;
 mClass(){}
 mClass(String first,String second){
    this.first=first;
    this.second=second;
 }
 public String getFirst(){
  return this.first;
 }
 public String getSecond(){
  return this.second;
 }
}
```

Now you can get the data in this class.

```
mClass mclass = datasnapshot.getValue(mClass.class);
```

Now where you want to use this data just call the getter function.

```
text.setText(mclass.getFirst());
```

Answer (score 0):

Modify your code

1. Initialize variables

   ```
   private FirebaseDatabase mFirebaseDatabase;
   private DatabaseReference mMessagesDatabaseReference;
   private ChildEventListener mChildEventListener;
   //for list view
   private ListView mListView;
   private MessageAdapter mAdapter;
   ```
2. In onCreate

   ```
   mFirebaseDatabase=FirebaseDatabase.getInstance();
   mMessagesDatabaseReference=mFirebaseDatabase.getReference().child("search").child("country").child("city").child("blood group"); 
   List<String> data = new ArrayList<>();
   mAdapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.data,data);
   mListView.setAdapter(mAdapter);

   dataRead();
   ```
3. dataRead method

   ```
   private void dataRead() {
       if ( mChildEventListener == null) {
       mChildEventListener = new ChildEventListener() {
           @Override
           public void onChildAdded(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {
           String value = dataSnapshot.getValue(String.class);
           mAdapter.add(value);
           }

           public void onChildChanged(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
           public void onChildRemoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot) {}
           public void onChildMoved(DataSnapshot dataSnapshot, String s) {}
           public void onCancelled(DatabaseError databaseError) {}
       };
       mMessagesDatabaseReference.addChildEventListener( mChildEventListener);
   }
      }
   ```
4. String.class should look like this. Note the public variables and empty constructor.

   ```
   public class User {
   public String user;
   public String emailId;
   public long timeStampStart;
   public long timeStampStop;
   public long diff;

   public User()
   {

   }
   public User(String user,String emailId,long timeStampStart,long timeStampStop,long diff)
   {
   this.user=user;
   this.emailId=emailId;
   this.timeStampStart=timeStampStart;
   this.timeStampStop=timeStampStop;
   this.diff=diff;
   }


   public String GetUser()
   {
   return user;
   }

   public String GetEmailId()
   {
   return emailId;
   }

   public long GetTimeStampStart()
   {  
   return timeStampStart;
   }
   public long GetTimeStampStop()
   {
   return timeStampStop;
   }

   public long GetDiff()
   {
   return diff;
   }

   public void setUser(String user)
   {
   this.user=user;
   }
   public void setEmailId(String emailId)
   {
   this.emailId=emailId;
   }
   public void setTimeStampStart(long timeStampStart)
   {
   this.timeStampStart=timeStampStart;
   }
   public void setTimeStampStop(long timeStampStop)
   {
   this.timeStampStop=timeStampStop;
   }

   public void setDiff(long diff)
   {
   this.diff=diff;
   }
   }
   ```
5. Now database should look like this. Modify according to your need

   ```
    search
       country
     -city
       -blood group
         -123
           abc:something
           bcd:something
   ```

   and let me know if any problem arises

Comment: Hello,, i have few questions about what you wrote here. First in 1: 
`private MessageAdapter mAdapter;` is giving me an error and there is no classes to import for it. it's not even available. In 2: 
`mAdapter = new Adapter(this, R.layout.data,data);` , R.layout.data is giving an error on data. In 3: `mAdapter.add(value)` , an error under .add . So i am assuming that they are related to the first part in 1. what am i supposed to do? Thank you

Comment: This code is working for me. Just change your variables according to your need. Here MessageAdapter is the class which contain ArrayAdapter code. R.layout.data is the reference to XML id of listview. Reference the exact classes then you can import the files. There are lot of tutorials available for list adapter.